# Testing main effects and interactions with rma from metafor

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I'm not sure how to test for main effects and interaction effects between multiple moderator variables in metafor. Am I doing this right?  My dataset is quite large, so we'll play with the iris dataset.

Create dataset

```
sp <- gsub("setosa", 0, iris$Species)
sp <- gsub("versicolor", 1, sp)
iris$Species <- as.numeric(gsub("virginica", 2, sp))
iris$var <- rep(c(0,1,2), nrow(iris)/3)
```

I think this is correctly testing for main and interaction effects between the two moderator variables `Species` and `var`

```
rma(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, mods = ~ Species * var -1, data = iris)


Mixed-Effects Model (k = 150; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     3.8158 (SE = 0.8043)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             1.9534
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 58.63%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   2.42

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 147) = 387.0300, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 1,2,3): 
QM(df = 3) = 574.7435, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

             estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
Species        3.8987  0.3038  12.8333  <.0001   3.3032   4.4941  ***
var            3.0421  0.2400  12.6769  <.0001   2.5718   3.5124  ***
Species:var   -1.8851  0.2761  -6.8284  <.0001  -2.4262  -1.3440  ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And this by adding `factor()` call to each moderator is simply getting estimates and CI's for each level of each moderator

```
rma(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, mods = ~ factor(Species) * factor(var) -1, data = iris)

Mixed-Effects Model (k = 150; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0 (SE = 0.2714)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 0.00%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   1.00

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 141) = 10.7649, p-val = 1.0000

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9): 
QM(df = 9) = 1666.4569, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

                               estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub     
factor(Species)0                 5.0488  0.2947  17.1332  <.0001   4.4712  5.6263  ***
factor(Species)1                 5.7185  0.4935  11.5867  <.0001   4.7512  6.6858  ***
factor(Species)2                 6.7073  0.5870  11.4267  <.0001   5.5568  7.8577  ***
factor(var)1                    -0.0596  0.4106  -0.1452  0.8845  -0.8645  0.7452     
factor(var)2                    -0.1082  0.4221  -0.2562  0.7978  -0.9354  0.7191     
factor(Species)1:factor(var)1    0.3329  0.8248   0.4036  0.6865  -1.2838  1.9495     
factor(Species)2:factor(var)1   -0.2557  0.9126  -0.2802  0.7793  -2.0445  1.5330     
factor(Species)1:factor(var)2    0.3598  0.8174   0.4402  0.6598  -1.2423  1.9620     
factor(Species)2:factor(var)2   -0.0776  0.9217  -0.0842  0.9329  -1.8841  1.7288     

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, the `0` level of the `var` variable is not in the second call to `rma`. Is there a different way to specify the model to get the estimates for that variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is really not metafor specific, but is more about proper understanding of the formula syntax and the coding of factor variables in R. The metafor package does nothing different than, for example, the `lm()` function (as far as setting up the model matrix is concerned). To see this, just try:

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ factor(Species) * factor(var) -1, data=iris))
```

Now back to your models. The first model (`rma(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, mods = ~ Species * var - 1, data = iris)`) does not make sense, because you are treating variables `Species` and `var` as numeric/quantitative covariates/predictors (I assume you really mean for `Species` and `var` to represent factors). Removing the intercept here is also not sensible, as it assumes that the outcome is (on average) equal to zero when `Species` and `var` are both equal to 0.

In the second model (`rma(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, mods = ~ factor(Species) * factor(var) -1, data = iris)`), R is creating dummy variables to code those two factors. By removing the intercept, you are getting the estimated mean for each level of the `Species` factor when the `var` level is 0. One cannot also get a coefficient for `var` level 0, as otherwise the design matrix would be overparameterized. You can reverse the order of the two factors in the formula and then you will get the estimated mean for each level of the `var` factor (when the `Species` level is 0), but now the `factor(Species)0` coefficient is dropped.

The remaining coefficients represent contrasts between various levels (combinations).

If you really just want the estimated mean for each `Species` and `var` combination, you can use:

```
rma(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, mods = ~ factor(var) : factor(Species) -1, data = iris)
```

which yields:

```
                               estimate      se     zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub     
factor(var)0:factor(Species)0    5.0488  0.2947  17.1332  <.0001  4.4712  5.6263  ***
factor(var)1:factor(Species)0    4.9891  0.2860  17.4458  <.0001  4.4286  5.5496  ***
factor(var)2:factor(Species)0    4.9406  0.3022  16.3488  <.0001  4.3483  5.5329  ***
factor(var)0:factor(Species)1    5.7185  0.4935  11.5867  <.0001  4.7512  6.6858  ***
factor(var)1:factor(Species)1    5.9918  0.5178  11.5708  <.0001  4.9768  7.0067  ***
factor(var)2:factor(Species)1    5.9702  0.4964  12.0257  <.0001  4.9971  6.9432  ***
factor(var)0:factor(Species)2    6.7073  0.5870  11.4267  <.0001  5.5568  7.8577  ***
factor(var)1:factor(Species)2    6.3919  0.5654  11.3044  <.0001  5.2837  7.5001  ***
factor(var)2:factor(Species)2    6.5215  0.5716  11.4086  <.0001  5.4011  7.6418  ***
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough answer. I'm still not clear on how to get the effects for each variable across all levels though. So what is the estimate for the var and Species variables. I just wonder if there is anything different about meta-analyses vs. regular linear models

Comment: Another question: In a mixed-model using `rma` is the between study variance by default specified as a random effect? Or is there a way to do that in the model specification?

Comment: No, as far as the modeling of the fixed effects is concerned, there is absolutely nothing different about meta-regression and regular linear models. And yes, if you use a random-effects model (which is the default for ``rma``), between-study variance is modeled as a random effect. If you include predictors/covariates/moderators, then the residual between-study variance is modeled as a random effect.