# How to compare post hoc tests when fitting no intercept models to traditional ANOVA research designs in regression [R, lm()]

Tags: r, regression, anova, treatment-effect

I am learning how to apply multilevel modelling to traditional factorial ANOVA research design: a pretest, treatment, and posttest design.

I learned that by excluding any intercepts for factors, I can fit a model letting each coefficient indicate the estimated mean score for each level ([Testing main effects and interactions with rma from metafor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81656/testing-main-effects-and-interactions-with-rma-from-metafor)).

This looks very simple and seems easy to interpret, compared with the usual multiple regression model, with which you have to do extra work to get estimated mean scores for each level. However, when I fit this model, most of the coefficients are significant (i.e., most of the estimated mean scores are significantly greater than 0), so that I cannot test the actual significance of the factors.

Is there any way I can compare levels and do post hoc tests?

```
sp <- gsub("setosa", 0, iris$Species)
sp <- gsub("versicolor", 1, sp)
iris$Species <- as.numeric(gsub("virginica", 2, sp))
iris$var <- rep(c(0,1,2), nrow(iris)/3)
fit <- lm (Sepal.Length ~ factor(Species):factor(var)-1, data = iris)
```

And here is the result I got:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ factor(Species):factor(var) - 1, 
    data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.54706 -0.31875 -0.05165  0.31618  1.32941 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
factor(Species)0:factor(var)0   5.0529     0.1249   40.47   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)1:factor(var)0   5.7706     0.1249   46.22   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)2:factor(var)0   6.7563     0.1287   52.50   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)0:factor(var)1   5.0118     0.1249   40.14   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)1:factor(var)1   6.0187     0.1287   46.77   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)2:factor(var)1   6.4471     0.1249   51.64   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)0:factor(var)2   4.9500     0.1287   38.46   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)1:factor(var)2   6.0235     0.1249   48.24   <2e-16 ***
factor(Species)2:factor(var)2   6.5706     0.1249   52.62   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5148 on 141 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9928,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9924 
F-statistic:  2174 on 9 and 141 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: When running your code, I get this error 
`fit <- lm (Sepal.Length ~ factor(Species):factor(var)-1, data = iris)
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors`
Are you sure these results are not due to an issue with the model?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, @Nakx. Sorry I forgot to include some more codes to set the data. Now, it should work.

Comment: What does this have to do with lme4??

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I initially meant to post the examples specifically post in case of lme4, but decided to use a simplified model (i.e. a general linear morel) thinking this may invite more answers. I will edit the title and tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
rvl suggested to use `library(emmeans)` and the `emmeans()` function instead of lsmeans, as lsmeans will be deprecated soon. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transition-from-lsmeans.html for more details.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
I think you are looking for the `lsmeans()` function of the `lsmeans` package.

> The lsmeans package provides a simple way of obtaining least-squares
>   means and contrasts thereof. It supports many models fitted by R core
>   packages (as well as a few key contributed ones) that fit linear or
>   mixed models, and provides a simple way of extending it to cover more
>   model classes.

You can use this formulation:

```
lsmeans(fit, pairwise ~ factor1 | factor2)
```

I would consider the use of the argument `adjust="none"` as you may not be interested in every pairwise comparison. You could always correct the p-values with any method you like for the pairwise comparisons that are of interest to you, but be aware that p-value adjustments is a tricky subject.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Nakx. This is exactly what I was looking for! Since my actual model includes 3 way interactions, the results is so many comparisons as you mentioned. I will take the p-values as **one** of the indicators, and check with confidence intervals as well. Thank you again and I hope you have a great day today.

Comment: But I suggest **emmeans** instead, which is the continuation of **lsmeans**. **lsmeans** will be deprecated in a year or so.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @rvl. I didn't know that. The difference I realize was `lsmeans()` provides p-values, whereas `emmeans()` does not. But as far as I checked, both package seems like provide the exactly same predicted values. Could you elaborate more on (1) when we should be careful using lsmeans, and (2) why `lsmeans()` will be deprecated?

Comment: `emmeans()` provides p values too - not sure why you think otherwise. For an explanation of the reasons, See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transition-from-lsmeans.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. That was really good to know. I will uaw `emmeans()` intead then. Thank you!